# constant expression required for a gnuscript which have a intermidiate step to modify the plotable script

Tags: awk, gnuplot

```
#!/usr/bin/gnuplot
Yi=-10
Yf=10
lshift=`grep MERGE case.dat | awk '{print $7}'`
print lshift

SHIFT=`cat CASE.gnu |  awk NF | awk '{print"    " $1,"    "   $2-lshift}' > 1 ; sed '/    `STATS_max    /{G;}' 1 > case.gnu
print SHIFT

set xrange [0:STATS_max ]
set yrange [Yi:Yf]
set xtics format ""

plot 'CASE.gnu' u 1:2:-2 w l lw 2.2 lc rgb "blue" lt 10 notitle
```

It gives me error ""case.gnu", line 19: constant expression required" in the line starting with SHIFT.

Comment: what is the output from that `cat` command?  Is it in quotes?

Comment: It is  two colum fle and can be found here   (XXXXwe.tl/t-GTTQBXbCfm)  . Replace XXXX with  https://

Comment: The point is that your "cat" command is malformed.  Note that the closing back-tick for the command that starts with cat is in the middle of the line, not the end of the line. When you try to set SHIFT equal to that mess, various error messages are expected.  I suggest that you split that series of operations into individual steps and debug them one at a time.

Comment: Thanks Ethan, that will be very difficult for me. My aim is to sbstract a variable from column number of two. That is stored in lshift in my main query. Menahile the format of the file CASE.gnu should not change.

Comment: I do not quite understand that description, but you can almost certainly do the same thing by defining a function in gnuplot and calling that function inside the `using` clause of the plot command.  Probably awk is not necessary at all.  Can you state more clearly what manipulation you need to do to the numbers in column 2 of your data file?  That way someone can tell you how to do it with a gnuplot function.

Comment: These data will give me a plot  where column 1 will be a x-axis and column 2 will be at Y-axis. colum 2 of original file needs to be shifted with a number that is grepped in lshift variable in the my main post (line number 3). Point to be notted here is that there are many blank line after a particular interval and direct substraction chages the format of the file.

Comment: Two things are unclear to me. (1) Please explain "shift".  Do you mean that the x coordinate input as x[i] is plotted with y coordinate y[i+lshift], where i is the row number in the input file? (2) What do you mean "changes the format of the file"?  Nothing you do inside gnuplot will change the original file content.

Comment: Hii, I have provided a link to download the CASE.gnu file. The data in this file are raw and  and column 2 of this file needs to be shifted with a number that is grepped at third line in the gnuscript (lshift=`grep MERGE case.dat | awk '{print $7}'`
). So my aim is that there should be some command that can go the same job that SHIFT command needs to do here.

Comment: the value of lshift is  and the value of STATS_max  is 6.9365. Now if you download the file from above link and run this comand on terminal, you will get case.gnu file which is of same formate that the original is having but the column two will be shifter by a constant number 8.5068. The command that is to be run on terminal is  cat BANDS_data.gnu |  awk NF | awk '{print"    " $1,"    "   $2-8.5068}' > 1  ; sed '/   6.9365    /{G;}' 1 > case.gnu

Comment: But you don't need awk for that.  Just tell gnuplot `plot "original_file.dat" using 1:($2-lshift)`.

Comment: It worked and it was so simple. Thanks Ethan